# Spring-data Cassandra query : missing EOF exception

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to query to cassandra table and trying to retrieve subset of row data based on my filter
But am getting exceptin as missing EOF

@ repository-

```
  @Query("select * from customer_request where product_id = ?0 and date_period = ?1 WHERE token(K) > token('offset') and token(K) < token('rowNumber')")
  List<CustomerRequest> findByProduct(String productId, String datePeriod,
  Integer offset, Integer rowNumber);
```

What am i doing wrong here?
[trying to add logic t get subset of row. at 1st request i will pass offset=0, and rowNumber =10]

error log:-

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:104 missing EOF at 'where' (...'PI_NAME_CHANGE' and receipt_period = '2016-02-06' [where] token...)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:269)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:183)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate$12.doInSession(CqlTemplate.java:503)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate$12.doInSession(CqlTemplate.java:494)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:471)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:494)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:483)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:393)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:420)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:414)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:454)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.findByProductIdAndReceiptPeriod(Unknown Source)
    at com.fmr.docgen.service.transaction.IncomingRequestServiceImpl.findCustomerRequest(IncomingRequestServiceImpl.java:96)
    at com.fmr.docgen.controller.TransactionController.findCustomerRequest(TransactionController.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

Comment: Can you post the complete exception stack trace please ?

Answer (score 1):

> WHERE token(K)

is **K** the name of your partition key column ?

> token('offset')

Shouldn't it be **token(?2)** instead ? Same remark for **token('rowNumber')**

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.